# uniform law on a subset of {0,1}^N

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Consider $N$ an integer and $k \in \{ 0, .., N\}$ and define
$$
\Gamma_k := \{ \omega \in \{ 0,1 \}^N, \:
\sum_{j=1}^N \omega_j = k  \}.
$$

The uniform law on $\Gamma_k$ satisfies
$$
\forall \omega \in \Gamma_k,\: p(\omega) =
\frac{k!(N-k)!}{N!} \: \mbox{(weight of $\omega$)}. 
$$

How do you simulate the uniform law on $\Gamma_k$?

Comment: What is p($\omega$)?

Comment: $p(\omega)$ is the weight assigned to $\omega$. Here all the $\omega \in \Gamma_k$ have the same weight.

Comment: What is weight?

Comment: Here $\sum_{\omega \in \Gamma_k} p(\omega) = 1$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_function